# Probabilities is P(X|Y) ~ Bin(n,p) same as P(Y|X) ~ Bin (n,p)?

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

In my sheet it says that P(X|N=n) follows Bin(n,p), and I want to know if it were P(N|X=x), would it follow the same distribution?

My question is if P(X|N=n) follows Bin(n,p) is it safe to say that P(N|X=x) also follows Bin(n,p).

Comment: Most likely $P(X|N=n)$ is a conditional probability and therefore has values in $[0,1]$ which it all can take.  I do not even believe that it follows $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ because such variables take values in $0,1,...,n$. If you think I miss something, more details please.

Comment: You can say, $X\mid N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(N, p)$ in which case $$\mathsf P(X{=}k\mid N{=}n)=\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq k\leq n}$$   Bayes' Rule would be used to determine the conditional distribution of $N$ given $X$, which requires knowing the marginal distribution of $N$. However, whatever that may be, it is certain that $N\mid X$ *shall not* be binomially distributed since $N$ would realise integer values of *at least* $X$.

Comment: Suppose $N$ is Poisson and $X\mid N = n$ is a Binomial random variable with probability of success $p$ on $n$ attempts. Then, $N \mid X = x$ defines a random variable that is supported (it assign positive probability to each element in) on $x + \mathbf{Z}_+,$ which clearly cannot be binomial.